# Why specify border-bottom-color when border-bottom-style is equal to 'none'?

Tags: html, css

I'm asking this question out of curiosity. Have seen the following a lot on Google Cloud's admin page:

```
border-bottom-color: rgb(127, 127, 127);
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
```

If the style is set to none, why bother with specifying other properties? What is it that the gurus know that folks like me are missing?

Comment: Without context this means nothing...it's possible it's set at `0` to be changed later.

Comment: Most likely, they're resetting it for future animations. It's also possible they need to override defaults so the `border` shorthand works in a particular way. Without context, your question is not answerable and not helping anyone. Remember the main reason for getting a question answered on SO is not people's drive to work for others for free, but the question's usefulness as well as the answer being available to future visitors needing it as well. In current form, this question is only useful to you and even that is questionable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change states it's common to add a border for things like highlighting or showing focus. Rather than specifying the same color for each state you can just specify width and style and make use of the good defaults that were already set.

That said we can't tell you why a Google employee did something in a particular way without one commenting specifically. Also be aware that they're regular programmers like you and me, not superheroes. They may have left it as a mistake. They may have added it for other reasons.